# Workbox service worker's caching does not appear to be immediately active on first load

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

In creating my service worker with the Workbox webpack plugin, I've set both `skipWaiting` and `clientsClaim` to true. On the first, initial load, with no prior service worker running, I see all of my pre-cached resources get loaded by the sw (presumably to put in cache) on the initial landing page.  One of these resources, we'll say `a.js`, does indeed show in the network tab as being loaded among these resources.

I then browse to a new section of my web app that uses `a.js`, and I do see `a.js` load in the network tab, but **not** from the service worker; it's loaded from the network like normal. It seems that on the first, initial load, the sw is running and caching resources, but not serving from cache.  Is this expected behavior?

To be clear, if I clear out all service workers, and again browse to the landing page, but then **refresh** and reload the landing page, **then** browse to that other section, I can indeed see `a.js` load from cache, form the service worker.  So it seems that the initial installation of the service worker does not result in it being completely active.

Is this expected, and if not, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `clientsClaim` and you're in clean-slate scenario, after the service worker has finished installing/activating, all network requests should trigger the service worker's `fetch` handler. So what you're seeing doesn't match up with what I'd expect.

You can [enable debugging in Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug#debugging_workbox) and see if there's anything useful logged in the scenario you suggest. In particular, make sure that the precaching step has completed and the service worker is fully activated at the time you make your `a.js` request.

You can also take a look at a list of controlled clients for the currently active service worker and confirm that the new tab you have open is on the list:

[image]